# I've just seen a book title 'What You Make It'. This is grammatically right, isn't it?

Tags: meaning, grammar

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_You_Make_It

Well, is it this structure, 'subject + verb + object + objective complement'?

And I heard the phrase 'Life is what you make it.' How about omitting 'it' in the sentence? Is it okay?  If the omitted sentence is not wrong, I think its meaning is quite different from the former, though.

Answer (score 1):

"What you make it" is not a sentence. It is a noun phrase, and the complement in the expression "Life is what you make it."

This expression is well known, so by just mentioning the complement will remind us of the full expression.

Titles are often not sentences. They are usually nouns, or noun phrases.

The expression is "Life is what you make it", the word "it" is part of the expression. If you omit "it" the meaning is different. The expression means that "you can choose what to do in you your life", without "it" it would mean "Life is the things that you make."

Comment: Now I clearly understand what that means. Thanks to you, James.